# What for a message browser would be available for activeMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a message / queue browser for activeMQ available? 
I tried Hermes JMS, but it is not working for activeMQ 5.10, anymore.

We need a browser where we can export a message into XML.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hermes is able to connect to AMQ but perhaps you need to use older AMQ libs on the client/hermes side, like v5.7.0 or similar.

Hawt.io is great to read/move/browse/delete/send messages but you may need additional tools to export/import data.

You cannot export a JMS message to XML in a generic way. What you can do is to export the payload to a file (which may be XML).

To export messages into a files, you can use a command line tool called [A](https://github.com/northlander/a). Then you can write `a -b tcp://localhost:61616 -c 20 -o file.xml MY.QUEUE` and you will have 20 messages exported to file-1.xml, file-2.xml .. file-20.xml.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of "A".

Comment: I've tried to use the command line tool A to export the queue contents (which partially worked). It shows the queue output in the console perfectly but the xml files that it generate just contain a line that says "no payload".
a -b tcp://localhost:61616 -c 0 -j -o file.xml DLQ.jms.integration.event.inbound
I am running version 1.4.8 of A - any clues as to what might be wrong ??

Comment: It should work, tested now with 1.4.8 and it works just fine. Maybe, try to add some more wait time. -w 1000

Answer (score 3):

You can try hawtio which is a web console that has plugins for various technologies, such as ActiveMQ.

hawtio is created by the people who also created Camel and ActiveMQ and thus has great plugins for those.

- http://hawt.io/

Comment: Thank you for these suggestion. I will give it a try. :)

Comment: Now i have to search for an export plugin.

Comment: Hi ... hawt.io is great. Export plugin doesn't exists. I would have a look on Petters A - Tool for export messages. Thanks.